# Merge two dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I am merging two csv(data frame) using below code:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv(file1,dtype={'student_id': str})
df = pd.read_csv(file2)
c=pd.merge(a,df,on='test_id',how='left')
c.to_csv('test1.csv', index=False)
```

I have the following CSV files

file1:

```
test_id, student_id
1, 01990
2, 02300
3, 05555
```

file2:

```
test_id, result
1, pass
3, fail
```

after merge

```
test_id, student_id , result
1, 1990, pass
2, 2300,
3, 5555, fail
```

If you notice student_id has 0 appended at the beginning and it's supposed to be considered as text but after merging and using `to_csv` function it converts it into numeric and removes leading 0.

How can I keep the column as "text" even after to_csv?

I think its to_csv function which saves back again as numeric
Added dtype={'student_id': str} while reading csv.. but while saving it as to_csv .. it again convert it to numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = pd.read_csv(file1, dtype={'test_id': object})
df = pd.read_csv(file2, dtype={'test_id': object})
```

==============================================================

```
In[28]: pd.merge(a, b, on='test_id', how='left')
Out[28]: 
  test_id   student_id  result
0      01         1990    pass
1      02         2300     NaN
2     003         5555    fail
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not dropping the leading zero on the `merge`, it's dropping it on the `read_csv`. You can fix this by specifying that column is a string at import time:

```
a = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', dtype={'student_id': str}, skipinitialspace=True)
```

The important part is the `dtype` parameter. You are telling pandas to import this column as a string. The `skipinitialspace` parameter is set to True, because the column headers are defined with spaces, so we strip it:

```
test_id, student_id
        ^ The student_id starts here, at the space
```

The final code looks like this:

```
a = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', dtype={'student_id': str}, skipinitialspace=True)
df = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
results = a.merge(df, how='left', on='test_id')
```

With the `results` dataframe looking like this:

```
    test_id     student_id  result
0   1           01990       pass
1   2           02300       NaN
2   3           05555       fail
```

Then when you run `to_csv` your result should be:

```
test_id,student_id, result
1,01990, pass
2,02300,
3,05555, fail
```

Comment: I tried your solution.  added "a = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', dtype={'student_id': str})". But after saving it as c.to_csv('test1.csv', index=False).. If you open this test1.csv file ... you will see the leading zeros are gone. So I think its to_csv function which removes the leading zeros. and considers it as numeric

Comment: @MadhuraMhatre, Are you sure about that? Open the CSV file in a text editor, not in Excel. Excel is lying to you. [Excel display](http://i.imgur.com/cVd7CFs.png) vs [Text Display](http://i.imgur.com/i3JuqX6.png). Remember, a CSV is NOT an excel document.

Answer (score 2):

***Caveat*** Please use `merge` or `join`.  This answer is provided to give perspective on the flexibility pandas gives you and how many different ways there are to answer the same question.

```
a = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', converters=dict(student_id=str), skipinitialspace=True)
df = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
results = pd.concat(
    [d.set_index('test_id') for d in [a, df]],
    axis=1, join='outer'
).reset_index()
```

Comment: phoooo, I think it is overcomplicated, what do you think?

Comment: Education... perspective on the many ways to get things done.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), first need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `dtype` for convert `student_id` to `string` and remove whitespaces by `skipinitialspace`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, dtype={'student_id': str}, skipinitialspace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, skipinitialspace=True)

df = df1.join(df2.set_index('test_id'), on='test_id')
print (df)
   test_id student_id  result
0        1      01990    pass
1        2      02300     NaN
2        3      05555    fail
```

Comment: tried your solution. added "a = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', dtype={'student_id': str})". But after saving it as c.to_csv('test1.csv', index=False).. If you open this test1.csv file ... you will see the leading zeros are gone. So I think its to_csv function which removes the leading zeros. and considers it as numeric

Comment: If use `dtype={'student_id': str}` then force column to string type. And I always test `to_csv`, it works perfectly. What is your version of pandas?

Comment: @jezrael, I suspect they are viewing the CSV in Excel. Excel is lying to them about that leading zero. I provided a quick screenshot of this on a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269346/merge-two-dataframe-in-pandas/43269787?noredirect=1#comment73625619_43269787) in my answer.

Comment: Hmmm. I always test with text editor, maybe it can be problem.